# Hydration of domain object instances

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine query to receive a single instance of a domain object:

```
$entity = $query->getSingleResult();
```

Now I would like to hydrate $entity AFTER I received it already, so that $entity is an array (like when receiving it using \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY).

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$doctrine->hydrate($entity, \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Is there way to achieve this using Doctrine?

Comment: Have you tried $entity->toArray()?

Comment: Doesn't work, because $entity is a simple object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, but haven't found it.
There are some infinite recursion problems with serializing entities because of circular referencing.

In the end, I rolled my own serialize function based on this [example](https://gist.github.com/1034079#file_serializable_entity.php)